# I want to append table row values one by one from ajax page into my page.but now it is displaying separate as table

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

**Ajax**

My ajax page here I want to display each product from the table that I have selected

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $("#mySelect").text();
    $("#prd_item").text();
    $("#prd_qty").text();
  });
  $('#filter').click(function() {
    var from_date = $('#mySelect').val();
    var to_date = $('#prd_item').val();
    var qty = $('#prd_qty').val();
    if (from_date != '' && to_date != '') {
      $.ajax({
        url: "product_filter.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
          from_date: from_date,
          to_date: to_date,
          qty: qty
        },
        success: function(data) {
          $('#order_table').append(data);
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

**action page**

Comment: add your code  not image

Comment: yes of course i have posted it

Comment: Does the `product_filter.php` endpoint return HTML code?

Comment: do include `order_table` and `product_filter.php`

Comment: `product_filter.php` should return data like `<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>`  .

Comment: how your data is coming in which format can you tell me then i can help you

Comment: too help you i have to know what extactly your ajax is returning & how you want to place it

Answer (score 1):

I dont Have `product_filter.php` code  but you want to append table, .  `product_filter.php` **should return value like data variable** .

eg .  `'<tr><td>Kakul</td><td>56</td></tr>'`;

so  make sure `product_filter.php` is returning value in `<tr><td>` formate

```js
$(document).ready(function(){   
          
          /* $('#filter').click(function(){  
                var data = '<tr><td>Kakul</td><td>56</td></tr>';
                $('#order_table').append(data);
            }); */
$('#filter').click(function(){  
    var from_date = $('#mySelect').val();
    var to_date = $('#prd_item').val();
    var qty = $('#prd_qty').val();
    if (from_date != '' && to_date != '') {
      $.ajax({
        url: "product_filter.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
          from_date: from_date,
          to_date: to_date,
          qty: qty
        },
        error: function(data) {
        
          data = '<tr><td>Kakul</td><td>56</td></tr>';  // rewritting data according to my table
          $('#order_table').append(data);
        }
      });
    }
  });  
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="order_table">
<tr>
  <th>NAME</th>
  <th>value</th>
 <tr>
 <tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>123</td>
 <tr>
 <tr>
  <td>Harry</td>
  <td>23</td>
 <tr>
</table>
<button id="filter">Append</button>
```

**update :** 
*product_filter.php*

```
    $output ="";
       if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) { 
          $i=1; 
          while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
             $output .= ' <tr> <td>$i</td> <td>'. $row["pr_name"]  .'</td> <td>'. $row["quantity"] .'</td> <td>'. $row["mrp"] .'</td> </tr> '; 
         $i++;
        }else{
             $output .='<tr> <td colspan="5">No Order Found</td> </tr>';
        } 

}
```

Comment: sir i couldn't add remaining code that shows some error while posting code.

Comment: i don't have the code of `product_filter.php` . can you share the output

Comment: its an basic idea how to append row in table. you should fix ur `product_filter.php` code . make sure its return value in `tr td` formate

Comment: if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
    {  $i=1;
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
           {  
                $output .= '  
                     <tr> 
                          <td><?php echo $i++; ?></td> 
                          <td>'. $row["pr_name"] .'</td> 
                          <td>'. $row["quantity"] .'</td> 
                          <td>'. $row["mrp"] .'</td>    
                     </tr>  
                ';  
           }  
      }

Comment: else  
      {  
           $output .= '  
                <tr>  
                     <td colspan="5">No Order Found</td>  
                </tr>  
           ';  
      }  
      $output .= '</table>';  
      echo $output;

Comment: remove `<table>`  tag. keep only `<tr>` and `<td>`

Comment: in case of no result `<tr> <td colspan="5">No Order Found</td> </tr>` .

Comment: i have removed <table> tag . please tell me then how it should be

Comment: $output .= '<tr> <td>' ; is it ?

Comment: `$output .= ' <tr> <td><?php echo $i++; ?></td> <td>'. $row["pr_name"] .'</td> <td>'. $row["quantity"] .'</td> <td>'. $row["mrp"] .'</td> </tr> '; `

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){   
      
       $('#filter').click(function(){  
            var data = '<tr><td>Kakul</td><td>56</td></tr>'; //how this will be in my code
            $('#order_table').append(data);
        });  
    });

Comment: or how to assign table row data to 'var data'

Comment: no need to assign . its your ajex responds . check the update.

Comment: no its in the ajax page 'append(data);  i mean this data'

Comment: now out put is ok. but each row displaying in different tables

Comment: make sure  '#order_table' is your table id . . and there are no table tag present in php file

Comment: sir its not working would you please provide your mail id.i can send the entire code.

Comment: kakul232@gmail.com

Comment: i have sent an email pls check